# Two examples of shared library problems, is this a 18.04 issue?

Tags: 18.04, libraries, shared-library

I've just tried to run this program and have had library problems. I have the right libraries, but the program is looking in the wrong place? Is there a fix?

EDIT: I should say that I installed this via a DEB file from [here:](https://nerdur.com/todour-pl/)

```
$ Todour 
 Todour: error while loading shared libraries: libxcb-keysyms.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


$ apt-file search libxcb-keysyms.so.1
 libxcb-keysyms1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-keysyms.so.1
 libxcb-keysyms1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-keysyms.so.1.0.0
```

As per request:

```
 $ ldd Todour | grep not
  ldd: ./Todour: No such file or directory
```

AND

```
 $ file Todour
 Todour: cannot open `Todour' (No such file or directory)
```

EDIT: I also tried this:

```
  $ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  $ Todour 
  Todour: error while loading shared libraries: libxcb-keysyms.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

I've also added the i386 dependancies as per this command:

```
 sudo apt install libxcb-keysyms1:i386
```

Still getting the ELF class response.

Comment: What is the program?

Comment: It must be an `i386` program. You need to add `i386` architecture.

Comment: Please add output of `file Todour` and `ldd Todour | grep not` to the question.

Comment: Done! And some more new info too!

Comment: @JasonMehmel see my updated answer. I got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue about dependencies was [created on GitHub project page](https://github.com/SverrirValgeirsson/Todour/issues/8), now it is fixed.

The binary is 32-bit, so we need to enable 32-bit support

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
```

then download the package

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://nerdur.com/Todour-v2.17.deb
```

and install it:

```
sudo apt install ./Todour-v2.17.deb
```

and enjoy:

[image: Todour 2.17]

---

Note: for original problem with dependencies for 2.16 see [previous revision](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1123045/7) of this answer.

Comment: I'm getting this response:        E: Unable to locate package libxcd-keysms1:i386

Comment: Done. I also tried exporting a library path. Notes in the main question. New error response!

Comment: Tip: no need to "find" the folder, there's a command for that, so `ldd "$(which Todour)"` and `file "$(which Todour)"` will do.

Comment: That worked, N0rbert! Thank you!

Comment: @JasonMehmel the dependency problems are solved with 2.17 version (see updated answer above).